# Time Reversal symmetry, Quaternions, and spin-1/2 systems

Tags: fermions, complex-numbers, time-reversal-symmetry, spin-statistics, cpt-symmetry

When one has a system with no spin and time reversal symmetry, one can conclude that the Hamiltonian entries (in a particular basis, of course) must all be real. Can something be said about the Hamiltonian when we have a spin-1/2 (or any odd multiple) system with time reversal symmetry?

I understand that when dealing with spin-1/2, the time reversal operator is given by $$\mathcal T=e^{-i\pi S_y/\hbar}\mathcal K.$$ And this leads to $\mathcal T^2 = -1.$ But what do I do next?

I've heard that this may have something to do with quaternions, but I only see this connection vaguely. Any directions will help.